# ASP.NET Membership Password?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

If I require a password to be between 7 and 16 characters and contain at least 1 numeric password and then send a temporary password that contains no numeric characters and % signs and the ^ sign, will the password fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be fine.  It only checks the complexity when you change it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so.  The check for password complexity requirements should only occur when the password is created or changed.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the temporary password will follow the rules that you have establish. I would use the MembershipUser method: ResetPassword, to create all temporary passwords for the users.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating all temporary passwords to match the password complexity rules.

However the rules are only enforced when the password is changed, not when you log in.

The percent symbol shouldn't be used just in case it's misinterpreted as escaped hex.